# Getting different bytes from the same audio file

Tags: java, audio-streaming

I am trying to convert the audio file to a standard format and read the bytes.

First thing I do is:

```
static void main(String [] args)
{
    File file = new File("/path/to/my/file.mp3");
    AudioInputStream source = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    AudioFormat sourceFormat = source.getFormat();

    AudioFormat convertFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                sourceFormat.getSampleRate(),
                16,
                sourceFormat.getChannels(),
                sourceFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                sourceFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);
    AudioInputStream convert1AIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(convertFormat, source);

    AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(
            44100,
            8,
            1,
            true,
            true);

    AudioInputStream target = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, convert1AIS);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];


    //Here come strange things
    target.read(buffer,0, buffer.length);


}
```

Every time I start the program, the buffer contains different bytes, i.e first 10 bytes, which I see in the debugger are never the same. What is wrong?

I have added the following libraries:
jl1.0.1.jar,
jtransform-2.4.jar,
mp3spi1.9.5.jar,
tritonus_remaining-0.3.6.jar,
tritonus_share.jar

OS. Ubuntu 14.04

java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: I haven't used this API, but it looks like you're trying to read MP3 as PCM, and that's just not going to work.  You need to use an MP3 codec to decode the MP3 as PCM before you can do anything else with it.

Comment: you have added all those libraries but where do you use them. mp3 needs to be read specifically audioinputstream doesnt support it thats why you added the libraries to begin with isnt it? go see some other examples on using these libraries to read mp3 or i will come back later

Answer (score 0):

The core thing is: it is **not** guaranteed that a call to *read* will always read the exact same amount of bytes from your input.

To the contrary, that [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) method returns the number of bytes read back to you. So you always need a **loop** that keeps reading until **all** expected bytes were really read!

Edit: given your comments: you are doing an audio **conversion** here; so my *guess* is: this process is simply not deterministic. In other words: the real input bytes for that MP3 file would always be the same; but your code runs transformations on that; and as said; those transformations are non-deterministic; and therefore creating slightly different results for each run.

Comment: I mean, the first 10 bytes are always different. Edited the original post.

Comment: I'm not sure  I understand. I would expect that the first 10 bytes should be always the same. No?

Comment: How can a conversion be a not deterministic process?

Comment: Because of a potential use of heuristics? By doing things in parallel; and potentially just going for first results coming in?

Comment: So there is no way to get the same result?

Comment: Me using the word *guessing* is ... that I can't say for sure. Maybe you are lucky and some other person comes by with more exact knowledge on this subject.